# How to achieve similar Facebook opacity effect with CSS3?

Tags: html, facebook, css

I am trying to achieve a CSS3 opacity similar to what Facebook uses for its "Comments" Social Plugin. The opacity has a sort of "glass-like" look as if you were looking through a window.

Here is a screenshot of what I am referring to:

[image]

Comment: Can you make the screen shot bigger so I can get an idea what it looks like....

Comment: @samccone -- here you go: http://bit.ly/ngIGnY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a cross browser solution

http://jsfiddle.net/3VbTC/2/

the trick is to nest the background div within a container div

Comment: I would +1 you for this answer but I'm not registered :(

Comment: @samccone -- I tried your solution, and it works great. Now I'm confused which solution to use? Based on the above conversation, it sounds like your solution has better cross-browser support. Then again...in situations like this, if anyone's visiting my "hi-fi" web app with IE6, are they still using a rotatory telephone and/or living in a cave??

Comment: its not just ie 6 ... look here for rgba support http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say either something like this

```
.element
{
    background-color: Black;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Or a transparent background image.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of opacity since it is inherited by all content contained within the div to which it is applied. RGBA is much better, but as someone pointed out, it's not cross-browser (thanks to our special friend IE). Transparent bkg image is probably best if you're worried about all that though. +1

Comment: The other way it can be done is to have an outer container using position relative. Then place an empty background div with the opacity settings and position absolute to fill the container and set a low z-index on it. Then also add the elements you dont want to be transparented(word?) with position absolute and a higher z-index inside the outer container. That will work.

EDIT: samccones answer is basically what I was saying. It works real nice and is cross-browser as he says.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `background` (or `background-color`) property to `rgba(255,255,255,0.3)` or similar.

Comment: @samccone, this is part of the CSS3 standard. For most web applications, graceful fallbacks will still enable users to use the website's functionality. I mean, there is no compelling reason to have to support browsers invented years ago, such as IE6.

Comment: But it is a simple fix so why not support it?

Comment: @samccone, the `RGBA` property is supported in *any* version of Chromium, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox  3 and up, Safari 3 and up, Opera 10 and up and Internet Explorer 9 and up. As you can see, almost all browsers (minus IE) have had this feature supported for a few major versions back..

Comment: Ha I know... Just we are supposed to provide the most correct answers .. No?  This one while just fine does not cover all the bases.. That is all

Comment: It is impossible to cover all bases. Plain impossible. There is just no method to support every browser that has ever been created, nor would it be feasible to. We have the idea (and design pattern) of 'graceful fallbacks' instead.